# "Error: Not a window" via Instagram App Browser

Tags: reactjs, instagram, sentry

I am getting the error "Error: Not a window" in our sentry logs. This error is only occurring for users using Instagram's browser.

In sentry, it says that the "function" for the exception is "setTimeout" and "addEventListener."

The sentry trace isn't really providing any other useful information as far as I can tell. I am not even sure whether or not users or noticing this problem / if it is affecting them because I can't reproduce it on my device, even with the instagram browser and the same OS.

Any knowledge on the instagram browser and how it behaves would be awesome, we've had some problems in the past with popups in their browser as well.

Thanks!!!

Comment: We have identical symptoms: also happens with the built-in Instagram browser (iOS only: android users seem unaffected) and with a stack that includes sentry & react.

Comment: We've been having the same error in our Sentry logs for the past month now and can't reproduce it or find any reason why it's there. Using React and Sentry.

Comment: same issue here, any update on this??

Comment: We're also having the same issue on React, Next.js, and Sentry